# Camera2 MediaRecorder - How to record in WebM format?

Tags: android, android-camera2, mediarecorder, webm

I want to record a video in WebM format with `Camera2` and `MediaRecorder`.

To do this, I'm using the [Camera2Video sample code on Github](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/Camera2Video). The sample shows the way to record in mp4 format, using back or front camera.

The MediaRecorder configuration is done in a single method:

```kotlin
    /** Creates a [MediaRecorder] instance using the provided [Surface] as input */
    private fun createRecorder(surface: Surface) = MediaRecorder().apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        setOutputFile(outputFile.absolutePath)
        setVideoEncodingBitRate(RECORDER_VIDEO_BITRATE)
        if (args.fps > 0) setVideoFrameRate(args.fps)
        setVideoSize(args.width, args.height)
        setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        setInputSurface(surface)
    }
```

And what I'm trying to do is to find a goof configuration to record in `webm`

```kotlin
    private fun createRecorder(surface: Surface) = MediaRecorder().apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.WEBM)
        setOutputFile(outputFile.absolutePath)
        setVideoEncodingBitRate(RECORDER_VIDEO_BITRATE)
        if (args.fps > 0) setVideoFrameRate(args.fps)
        setVideoSize(args.width, args.height)
        setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.VP8)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.VORBIS)
        setInputSurface(surface)
    }
```

But, doing this, I'm facing a crash:

> 2020-12-09 14:59:26.560 28899-28899/com.android.example.camera2.video W/CameraDevice-JV-0: Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:543: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided
> 2020-12-09 14:59:26.564 28899-28899/com.android.example.camera2.video E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Failed to create capture session; configuration failed
> 2020-12-09 14:59:26.566 28899-28945/com.android.example.camera2.video E/CameraFragment: Camera 0 session configuration failed
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera 0 session configuration failed
> at com.example.android.camera2.video.fragments.CameraFragment$createCaptureSession$$inlined$suspendCoroutine$lambda$1.onConfigureFailed(CameraFragment.kt:375)
> at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy.lambda$onConfigureFailed$1(CallbackProxies.java:64)
> at android.hardware.camera2.impl.-$$Lambda$CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy$gvbTsp9UPpKJAbdycdci_ZW5BeI.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
> 2020-12-09 14:59:26.607 28899-28899/com.android.example.camera2.video E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.android.example.camera2.video, PID: 28899
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Camera 0 session configuration failed
> at com.example.android.camera2.video.fragments.CameraFragment$createCaptureSession$$inlined$suspendCoroutine$lambda$1.onConfigureFailed(CameraFragment.kt:375)
> at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy.lambda$onConfigureFailed$1(CallbackProxies.java:64)
> at android.hardware.camera2.impl.-$$Lambda$CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy$gvbTsp9UPpKJAbdycdci_ZW5BeI.run(Unknown Source:4)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
> at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)

The first line tells me there is a misconfiguration

> Stream configuration failed due to: endConfigure:543: Camera 0: Unsupported set of inputs/outputs provided

I tried to comment lines about audio source too because [I see that Vorbis Encoder is not supported](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats#audio-formats) with the same results.

How can I record a video in WebM format ?

Comment: It's likely that the encoder for the MediaRecorder didn't actually get created, so when you try to use the Surface from the MediaRecorder with the camera, it's not actually set up.  Are there any logcat output lines that suggest that the MediaRecorder ran into an error?

Comment: There are no more logcat outputs. And yes, to my mind, it is a MediaRecorder configuration error, but I don't know why and what ? Because all if ok with MP4 parameters

Comment: You want the whole-system logcat, not just logcat limited to your own app process.